# Using OpenLayers - seeking example for saving feature to database using Ajax

Tags: openlayers-2

I'm trying to save a point to the database using a balloon that has an input field and a save button. The button triggers the code and sends the feature info to the PHP page.
It works, but the save action refreshes the page. I would like it to save in the background without refreshing the page, like Ajax.

Can someone advise how to do this ?

```
   var mySaveStrategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Save({ auto: true });      
   var myProtocolHTTP = new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({ 
            url: "proc/newPoint.php", 
            params: { 
                    m: 'r', 
                    srs: 'EPSG:4326' 
            }, 
            callback: function() { alert("User callback called!"); }, 
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({ 
                    ignoreExtraDims: true, 
                    internalProjection: map.baseLayer.projection
            }) 
    });
```

I edited the code to reflect my latest code (16.12.2012):

```
        function handler(request) {
            alert(request.responseXML);
                        }




        var myProtocolHTTP = OpenLayers.Request.POST({
            url: "api.php?action=insertPOI",
            data: "",
            params: {
                m: 'r',
                srs: 'EPSG:4326'
            },
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "text/plain"
            },
            callback: handler
        });


    function formAction(action) {
        var feature = mytoolbar.selCtrl.openpopup.feature;
        switch (action) {
            case 'delete':
                feature.state = OpenLayers.State.DELETE;
                vectorLayer.strategies[0].save();
                break;
            case 'cancel':
                break;
            case 'save':
                var attrs = feature.attributes;
                attrs.name = $('fname').value;
                attrs.name_lat = $('fname_alt').value;
                attrs.type = $('ftype').value;
                attrs.notes = $('fnotes').value;

                if (feature.mystate) {
                    feature.mystate = null;
                    feature.state = OpenLayers.State.INSERT;
                    var ctrl = mytoolbar.controls[1];
                    ctrl.layer.addFeatures([feature]);
                    ctrl.featureAdded(feature);
                    ctrl.events.triggerEvent("featureadded", {'feature': feature});
                } else {
                    feature.state = OpenLayers.State.UPDATE;
                    vectorLayer.strategies[0].save();
                }
               break;

        }

    function getPopupForm(feature, context) {

        var gid      = feature.attributes.gid      || '';
        var name     = feature.attributes.name     || '';
        var name_alt = feature.attributes.name_alt || '';
        var notes    = feature.attributes.notes    || '';
        var html = "<div>" +
            "<form action='' name='baloon'>" +
               "<input id='fgid' type='hidden' value='" +
                  gid + "' />" +
               "<button type='submit'  id='baloon-save' value='Save' onClick=\"formAction('save')\" />"+
               "</td><td align='right'>" +
               "<div class='select-line'>"+
               "<button type='submit' id='baloon-cancel' value='Cancel' onClick=\"formAction('cancel')\" />&nbsp;" +
               "</div><div class='select-line'>"+
               "<button type='submit' id='baloon-delete' value='Delete' onClick=\"formAction('delete')\" /></div>"+
               "</td></tr></table></form>" +
           "</div>";

        return html;
    }
```

'

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: My one LINE solution is what worked for me. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your callback function to actually handle the the response: some examples are given here:
http://docs.openlayers.org/library/request.html

Comment: I tried your suggestion, still having the same problem. i edited my question to reflect more of the code, maybe im missing something.thanks

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things you could try:

Try returning false on your formAction

```
function formAction(action) {
 ...
 return false;
}
```

or you could try returning false here:

```
<button type='submit'  id='baloon-save' value='Save' onClick=\"formAction('save'); return false;\" />"+
```

[Reference](http://forums.asp.net/t/1115206.aspx/1)

Comment: Did you try `return false` at the end of `formAction`?